# system.missingmethodexception: 'method not found: void sqlite.sqliteconnection..ctor(string,sqlite.sqliteopenflags,bool,object)'

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

Added **SQLite** to my shared project on xamarin but it failed, when I run it on android I get the following error

```
system.missingmethodexception: 'method not found: void sqlite.sqliteconnection..ctor(string,sqlite.sqliteopenflags,bool,object)'
```

I tried to clean and delete bin obj folder with no success

[image]

Comment: which sqlite nuget are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an older/outdated reference for System.Data.SQLite;?